# System.Windows.Visibility Collapsed vs Hidden

Tags: wpf, user-interface, layout, wpf-controls

I have a control with Visibility set to "Collapsed" and a ToggleButton that changes the visibility between Visibility.Collapsed and Visibility.Hidden.  According to the  [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx) there should be no space allotted for the control within the layout when the control's Visibility is set to "Collaped," but there are no visual differences between the two enumerations. Additionally, the Visibility  of the control is initially set to Collapsed so the initial drawing of the controls should not allot any space for the control.

Is there a concept I am missing, or how do I get an element to take space only when visible?  My end-goal is to have controls appear on conditions based on user-selections that appear north of said display-varied controls, with consistent margins between all controls .

XAML Snippet:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="hideTest" DataContext="{StaticResource persistentMemoryBridge}"   Text="HIDETEST" Margin="0,327,31,491" Foreground="Black" Background="Orange" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <TextBox DataContext="{StaticResource persistentMemoryBridge}"   Text="{Binding Path=PropertyTest}" Margin="0,386,31,432" Foreground="Black" Background="Yellow"/>
    <ToggleButton Name="tbVisibility" Content="Toggle" Click="ToggleButton_Click" Margin="0,445,65,391"></ToggleButton>
</StackPanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```cs
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        switch (hideTest.Visibility) {
            case System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed: {
                hideTest.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                tbVisibility.Content = "Hidden";
                break;    
            }
        case System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden: {
            hideTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            tbVisibility.Content = "Visible";    
            break;
            }
        case System.Windows.Visibility.Visible: {
            hideTest.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            tbVisibility.Content = "Collapsed";
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use margins like that. Use another type of container such as a `Grid` or a `DockPanel`

Comment: This comment is a bit unclear.  If there is normally a margin of 10 on top/bottom and the control. height 50. is collapsed, expected margin between stacked controls should be 20, not 70.

Comment: Still, don't use margins like that. Period.

Comment: Like, what? There is very little reference to margins in this post at all.  You need to be more clear.

Comment: What kind of layout is `Margin="0,386,31,432"`?? Looks like you dragged and dropped UI elements in the designer. WPF is not for drag and droppers.

Comment: "expected margin between stacked controls should be 20, not 90"

Comment: If the the expected Margin between controls is 20, why are they all set in the 100's ???

Comment: the expected relative margin between the controls should be 20... im altering the code now.

Comment: @sammarcow There's a good chance that margins are respected even if the control is collapsed. Check this.

Comment: Voroinp, please post this as an answer.  Margins override Visibility.

Comment: Basically, collapsed means a complete measure and arrange, this is a disadvantage of performance, especially for those control that has complex visual tree, you have to avoid of using it, only if you do have a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When contol's visibility is in `Collapsed` state its margins do not participate in the layout (contrary to `Hidden` state)

Can be verified easily:

```
<Window x:Class="MarginsRespectForCollapsedTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Margin="50,50" Visibility="Collapsed">I'm Collapsed</Button>
        <Button>I'm Visible!</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I agree with HighCore that you XAML really looks like you just dragged controls from the toolbox panel. VS's XAML designer has this unpleasant feature: it tries to position controls with the help of margins.

Comment: I typed the XAML, then went to the designer to quickly position the elements for the purposes of learning the controls and WPF architecture.  I realize that is now a mistake.   Collapse (and Margin on all the controls within a StackPanel) Properties are now respected.